# Can Python's optparse display the default value of an option?

Tags: python, optparse

Is there a way to make Python's optparse print the default value of an option or flag when showing the help with --help?

Comment: See this SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12151306/argparse-way-to-include-default-values-in-help

Comment: If somebody seeks the same for Argparse: [Argparse: Way to include default values in '--help'?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12151325/562769)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Try using the `%default` string placeholder:

```
# This example taken from http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html#generating-help
parser.add_option("-m", "--mode",
                  default="intermediate",
                  help="interaction mode: novice, intermediate, "
                       "or expert [default: %default]")
```

Answer (score 8):

And if you want to add default values automatically to all options that you have specified, you can do the following:

```
for option in parser.option_list:
    if option.default != ("NO", "DEFAULT"):
        option.help += (" " if option.help else "") + "[default: %default]"
```

Answer (score 7):

And if you need programmatic access to the default values, you can get to them via the `defaults` attribute of the parser (it's a dict)

Answer (score 0):

The comments to your question already indicate there's another way to parse arguments called [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/argparse.html). It's been introduced in Python 3.2. It actually deprecates `optparse` but is used similarly.

`argpass` comes with different formatting classes and for instance `argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter` will also print the default values without you having to manipulate the help string manually.

> ArgumentParser objects allow the help formatting to be customized by
>   specifying an alternate formatting class. Currently, there are four
>   such classes:
>
> class argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter
>
> class argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter
>
> class argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter
>
> class argparse.MetavarTypeHelpFormatter

An example from the python docs:

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
...     prog='PROG',
...     formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo', type=int, default=42, help='FOO!')
>>> parser.add_argument('bar', nargs='*', default=[1, 2, 3], help='BAR!')
>>> parser.print_help()
usage: PROG [-h] [--foo FOO] [bar [bar ...]]

positional arguments:
 bar         BAR! (default: [1, 2, 3])

optional arguments:
 -h, --help  show this help message and exit
 --foo FOO   FOO! (default: 42)
```

see [argparse formatting classes](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/argparse.html#formatter-class)

Answer (score 0):

Add [argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#formatter-class) to your parser

```
    import argparse

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description='Your application description',
    formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
```

from documentation:

> ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter automatically adds information about
>   default values to each of the argument help messages:
>   Blockquote