# Argparse: Way to include default values in '--help'?

Tags: python, argparse

Suppose I have the following argparse snippet:

```
diags.cmdln_parser.add_argument( '--scan-time',
                     action  = 'store',
                     nargs   = '?',
                     type    = int,
                     default = 5,
                     help    = "Wait SCAN-TIME seconds between status checks.")
```

Currently, `--help` returns:

```
usage: connection_check.py [-h]
                             [--version] [--scan-time [SCAN_TIME]]

          Test the reliability/uptime of a connection.



optional arguments:
-h, --help            show this help message and exit
--version             show program's version number and exit
--scan-time [SCAN_TIME]
                    Wait SCAN-TIME seconds between status checks.
```

I would prefer something like:

```
--scan-time [SCAN_TIME]
                    Wait SCAN-TIME seconds between status checks.
                    (Default = 5)
```

Peeking at the help formatter code revealed limited options.  Is there a clever way to get `argparse` to print the default value for `--scan-time` in a similar fashion, or should I just subclass the `help` formatter?

Comment: You may be interested in [docopt](https://github.com/docopt/docopt). I've never looked at argparse again.

Comment: @PauloScardine - Being built in to the language is a major benefit for argparse.

Comment: @PauloScardine: Pulling a non-standard library into my current project will indeed be a pain, but I sure like the look of docopt's output.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @JS. you say "Pulling a non-standard library into my current project will indeed be a pain" Really? There are plenty of very useful libraries at pypi. In my context it is easy to pull in a non-standard library. It is sad, if it is hard in your context.

Comment: @guettli: That project was for a commercial embedded project.  You're right installation was easy.  Getting approval from corporate legal was a nightmare.

Answer (score 668, accepted):

Use the [`argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter` formatter](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#formatter-class):

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    # ... other options ...
    formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
```

To quote the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#formatter-class):

> The other formatter class available, `ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter`, will add information about the default value of each of the arguments.

Note that **this only applies to arguments that have help text defined**; with no `help` value for an argument, there is no help message to add  information about the default value *to*.

The exact output for your scan-time option then becomes:

```
  --scan-time [SCAN_TIME]
                        Wait SCAN-TIME seconds between status checks.
                        (default: 5)
```

Comment: Can I control that only the arguments with an explicit `default=` show the default value? Since I don't like the 'default: None' texts.

Comment: You can set the `default` to `SUPPRESS`: `default=argparse.SUPPRESS`. Note that in that case no attribute will be added to the namespace result if that argument was omitted, see [the `default` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#default).

Comment: Note that you need to specify this for each subparser created as well.

Comment: I just get, e.g. optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --dataset DATASET
       ............. instead of   --dataset DATASET (default: "MNIST")

Comment: Then create a new question, including a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. As I said, it works for me with Python 2.7.

Comment: This only works for optional args, not positional args.

Comment: @SomeGuyOnAComputer that’s because positional args don’t have their own help text. Only their metavar is used, in the generated *usage* line. Your only options are to supply your own `usage`, `description` or `epilog` parameters with the defaults manually included (because there could be multiple such values for multiple options, `argparse` can't do this for you).

Comment: What do I do if I've already set a `formatter_class`?

Comment: @AzorAhai: depends. What formatter class did you set?

Comment: @MartijnPieters `RawTextHelpFormatter`

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- create a new class that subclasses both and use that as the formatter; e.g. `class RawTextArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter(argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter, argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter): pass`, `parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(..., formatter_class=RawTextArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)`. The two variants override two different aspects of the base help formatter and so can be combined trivially.

Answer (score 300):

Add `'%(default)s'` to the help parameter to control what is displayed.

```
parser.add_argument("--type", default="toto", choices=["toto","titi"],
                              help = "type (default: %(default)s)")
```

**Notes**:

- It is `%`+ default in parenthesis + format characters (not to be confused with curly brackets `{default}` we find in `format` or f-string)
- Don't forget to add the "specifier character" for the type representation at the end (i.e. `s` for strings, `d` for integers, `f` for floats, etc.)
- You can also add the usual "printf" format specifiers (like number of digits for floats, leading zeros, etc.)

You can refer to [printf documentation](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) for more details.

Comment: I like this option because I'd already used the format_class=argparse.RawTestHelpFormatter and didn't feel like farting around with OOP.

Comment: Don't forget to include the variable 'type' in your formatting string-- e.g. '%(default)s' for a string, or '%(default)d' for a digit.

Comment: I like this solution much better, it's far simpler, and I don't have to explicitly handle arguments with no default values.

Comment: @mqsoh multiple inheritance actually just worked, but unfortunately is not public API: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52025430/895245

Comment: I like this because changing the formatter class adds a bunch of "(default: None)" everywhere which is cluttering the help.

Comment: Is there a Python3-esque way of doing this? `str.format` won't work, because named arguments like `{default}` got removed in 3.8.

Comment: @Noldorin It works perfectly on my 3.8.1 install. Are you sure you used `%(default)s` and not `{default}`? (i.e. with parenthesis and not curly brackets)

Comment: I set `help=" "`, and it shows the default

Comment: I used `help="%(type)s (default: %(default)s)"` (with `%(type)s` rather than just `type`), and it seems like argparse is happy to fill in your type as well

Answer (score 22):

**Wrapper class**

This is the most reliable and DRY approach I've found so far to both show defaults and use another formatter such as `argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter` at the same time:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse

class ArgumentParserWithDefaults(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    def add_argument(self, *args, help=None, default=None, **kwargs):
        if help is not None:
            kwargs['help'] = help
        if default is not None and args[0] != '-h':
            kwargs['default'] = default
            if help is not None:
                kwargs['help'] += ' Default: {}'.format(default)
        super().add_argument(*args, **kwargs)

parser = ArgumentParserWithDefaults(
    formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter
)
parser.add_argument('-a', default=13, help='''my help
for a''')
parser.add_argument('-b', default=42, help='''my help
for b''')
parser.add_argument('--no-default', help='''my help
for no-default''')
parser.add_argument('--no-help', default=101)

parser.print_help()
print()
print(parser.parse_args())
```

Output:

```
usage: main.py [-h] [-a A] [-b B] [--no-default NO_DEFAULT]
               [--no-help NO_HELP]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -a A                  my help
                        for a Default: 13
  -b B                  my help
                        for b Default: 42
  --no-default NO_DEFAULT
                        my help
                        for no-default
  --no-help NO_HELP

Namespace(a=13, b=42, no_default=None, no_help=101)
```

**`ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter` + `RawTextHelpFormatter` multiple inheritance**

Multiple inheritance just works, but it does not seem to be public API:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse

class RawTextArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter(
    argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter,
    argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter
):
    pass

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    formatter_class=RawTextArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter
)
parser.add_argument('-a', default=13, help='''my help
for a''')
parser.add_argument('-b', default=42, help='''my help
for b''')
parser.print_help()
```

Output:

```
usage: a.py [-h] [-a A] [-b B]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -a A        my help
              for a (default: 13)
  -b B        my help
              for b (default: 42)
```

It just works works because as we can see trivially from the sources https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.5/Lib/argparse.py#L648 that:

- `RawTextHelpFormatter` implements `_split_lines`
- `ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter` implements `_get_help_string`

so we can guess that they will work together just fine.

However, this does not seem to be public API, and neither are the methods of `formatter_class`, so I don't think there is a public API way to do it currently. `argparse` docstring says:

> All other classes in this module are considered implementation details.
> (Also note that HelpFormatter and RawDescriptionHelpFormatter are only
> considered public as object names -- the API of the formatter objects is
> still considered an implementation detail.)

See also: [Customize argparse help message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35847084/customize-argparse-help-message/35848313)

Tested on Python 3.6.5.

Comment: Great ! Finally have both the formatted docstring And default arguments printed. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

It is often useful to be able to *automatically* include the `default` values in the help output, but only those that were *explicitly* specified (with `default=..`). The methods already mentioned have some shortcomings in this respect:

- The `ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter` [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12151325) prints out `(default: None)` for every argument whose default was not explicitly specified, and `(default: False)` for 'flags' (`action='store_true'`). This clutters the help output. To avoid it, `default=argparse.SUPPRESS` needs to be manually added for each such argument.
- The `'%(default)s'` [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18507871) requires manually adding it to all the arguments' `help` strings that we *do* want printed in help.

Both methods end up needing manual intervention to print out only the "right" defaults.
One way to do this automatically is to augment the `ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter` to ignore the `None`s and `False`s default values:

```py
class ExplicitDefaultsHelpFormatter(argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter):
    def _get_help_string(self, action):
        if action.default is None or action.default is False:
            return action.help
        return super()._get_help_string(action)
```

Use it in place of `ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter`:

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        formatter_class=ExplicitDefaultsHelpFormatter
                )
```

This will print only the explicitly set `default` values in the help output.

Note: if an argument's default was explicitly set as `None` or `False`, it won't be shown in help with this class; add `%(default)s` string to `help` for that argument if you want it in the help output.

Comment: This does not display the default for arguments with default=0. Alternative: `if action.default is None or action.default is False`.

Comment: @sfinkens Thanks for pointing that out! It was due to an implicit `int` → `bool` type conversion in the `in` check. I have replaced that line with the `is` test, as in your suggestion.