# Is it possible to use more than one formatter for the help string of Python's argparse module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, argparse

The [argparse documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#formatter-class) speaks of four different formatter classes to control the output of the help string to some extend. I find several of them useful.

**Can I use several of them together?**

E.g. `argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter` and `argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter`

Comment: as I know you can create own formatter. And probably it should be described in documentation.

Comment: [Customize argparse help message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35847084/customize-argparse-help-message) - in one of answer you can see how to create own formatter.

Comment: Yes you can use several together.  One way is to define a new formater subclass that inherits from existing ones.  Also take sometime to look at how those classes change the base class.  They just redefine a couple of the methods.  In particular note how one of those classes just adds a `' (default: %(default)s)'` string to all your `help` lines.