# Different levels of help verbosity in argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I have an application with several dozens of CLI parameters. I use python argparse to parse arguments. Most of them are rarely used, only 5 or 6 are frequent. I don't want to clutter up the output of `--help` for simple cases, however there still should be a possibility to see description for all parameters somehow.

It is possible to have several verbosity levels for help in argparse? Here's how I expect it to be.

```
$ myapp -h
optional arguments:
 --foo         Do foo stuff
 --bar         Do bar stuff

$ myapp -hh # or myapp --expert-mode -h
optional arguments:
  --foo         Do foo stuff
  --bar         Do bar stuff

expert arguments:
  --use-warp-drive
  --no-fasten-seatbelts
... 50 more arguments
```

My first idea was to create two ArgumentParser-s, the basic one and the verbose one. First, `parse_args` of the basic was called. If `--expert` flag is present, the verbose parser is created and called. The approach has two downsides. First, `-h` is unconditionally handled by the first parser, so I should implement my own analogous help flag. Second, expert options are not even parsed without `--expert` flag, and I want them to be parsed unconditionally (but not to pop up in help).

Note: the solution should be python2 compliant.

---

**Update**: using the ideas from Lior Cohen's answer and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35847084/customize-argparse-help-message) question, I created a working example. In my case it was easier to make a whitelist of "simple" options, so it was even unnecessary to use tagged action types.

Illustrating code follows.

```py
class ExpertHelpFormatter(argparse.HelpFormatter):
    skip_expert_section = True
    whitelist = set(("foo",))

    def add_usage(self, usage, actions, groups, prefix=None):
        if self.skip_expert_section:
            actions = [action for action in actions if action.dest in self.whitelist]
        ret = super(ExpertHelpFormatter, self).add_usage(usage, actions, groups, prefix)
        if self.skip_expert_section:
            self.add_text("Use -hh for detailed help.")
        return ret

    def add_argument(self, action):
        if self.skip_expert_section and action.dest not in self.whitelist:
            return
        super(ExpertHelpFormatter, self).add_argument(action)

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False, formatter_class=ExpertHelpFormatter)

    parser.add_argument("-h", "--help", action="count", default=0)
    parser.add_argument("--foo")
    parser.add_argument("--use-warp-drive", action="store_true")

    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.help == 1:
        print parser.format_help()
        return
    elif args.help > 1:
        ExpertHelpFormatter.skip_expert_section = False
        print parser.format_help()
        return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a layout that should give you what you need, though it is not "free of work".

1. Disable default help by `add_help = False` (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#add-help)). this will let you still use *-h* and *--help* with action you want.
2. You need to "tag" your expert arguments by [type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#type) that will store somehow the fact that `foo` is "'simple" and `use-warp-drive` is "expert". You can add an attribute to the `Action` or save a global dict in the parser itself.
3. Write an *Help Formatter* (you can see [example](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/41b223d29cdfeb1f222c12c3abaccc3bc128f5e7/Lib/argparse.py#L673)). Then, according to the above "tag", you can suppress the "expert" help by returning `""` in case of "simple" mode.

Hope this is helping.

Comment: Thanks, custom formatters did their job. I included the example to my question in the edit. However, the docs for argparse state that methods of HelpFormatter are not a part of API, only class names are. In the solution I had to override `add_usage` and `add_argument`. Did you had in mind any solutions without exploiting non-public methods?

Comment: IMHO this can be done w/o override. `type` is a documented argument that takes your argument and do something, `formatter_class` is  documented too

Comment: While those are indeed documented, specific behavior of the formatter on actions is not. How can I adjust it without implementing my own override of `add_argument`? I can't see any way of injecting the dependency on type otherwise.

Comment: for example you can create a  callable `expert_int(arg)` that wraps `int` but also inject the fact that it is arg is "expert" to a dict you hold on the parser as another attribute.

Comment: The problem is not in checking if the arg is expert or not: I have a whitelist of non-expert items, and it can be simply hardcoded. The problem is how to detect expert arguments in the formatter without overriding its methods and choose whether to show help.