# Python argparse: Is there a way to print help for only a specific parameter?

Tags: python, argparse

I have a long list of parameters, so the output from `mycommand --help` is getting very big. I would like to provide my users a way to get the help text for only a specific parameter.

Something like this (doesn't work, shows the whole help text)

```sh
mycommand --help --parameter-of-interest
```

I don't want to split everything into subparsers if at all avoidable.

Comment: How about using grep ?

Comment: grep wouldnt work for multi-line argument descriptions (also, it needs to be dead simple for users not familiar with grep, or even on windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own actions to achieve this. Both of these will iterate the optional arguments and suppress any that are not found in `sys.argv`. I'd recommend the explain action as this doesn't mess with the `-h/--help` flag.

#### Explain Action

This creates an action `ExplainParamsAction` with the corresponding `-e/--explain` options that filters the help text for just specified parameters.

```py
import sys
import argparse

class ExplainParamsAction(argparse.Action):
    def __init__(
        self,
        option_strings,
        dest=argparse.SUPPRESS,
        default=argparse.SUPPRESS,
        **kwargs
    ):
        super().__init__(option_strings, dest, default=default, nargs=0, **kwargs)

    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        opts = parser._option_string_actions
        for arg in opts:
            if arg not in sys.argv:
                setattr(opts[arg], "help", argparse.SUPPRESS)
        parser.print_help()
        parser.exit()

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    "-e",
    "--explain",
    action=ExplainParamsAction,
    help="Show help message for only specified parameters and exit",
)
parser.add_argument("--url", help="URL to the resource")
parser.add_argument("--port", help="Port to the resource")
parser.add_argument("--timeout", help="Connection timeout")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

#### Override the Help Action

Alternatively you can override the help action that you supply to your parser.
To use with an [`argparse.ArgumentParser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser) you need to turn off the default helper and provide your own.

```py
import sys
import argparse

class _CustomHelpAction(argparse._HelpAction):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        args = sys.argv[1:]
        opts = parser._option_string_actions
        # Check is needed for just -h/--help to work
        if len(args) > 1:
            for arg in opts:
                if arg not in args:
                    setattr(opts[arg], "help", argparse.SUPPRESS)
        super().__call__(parser, namespace, values, option_string)


# Init parser with help turned off
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)

# Register your help action and manually add the `-h/--help` option
parser.register("action", "help", _CustomHelpAction)
parser.add_argument("-h", "--help", action="help", help="show this help message and exit")

# Add remaining arguments
parser.add_argument("--url", help="URL to the resource")
parser.add_argument("--port", help="Port to the resource")
parser.add_argument("--timeout", help="Connection timeout")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

---

#### Example usage:

All help:

```sh
python3 script.py --help
usage: script.py [-h] [--url URL] [--port PORT] [--timeout TIMEOUT]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help
  --url URL          URL to the resource
  --port PORT        Port to the resource
  --timeout TIMEOUT  Connection timeout
```

Specific parameters:

```sh
~ python3 script.py -h --url --timeout
usage: script.py [--url URL] [--timeout TIMEOUT]

optional arguments:
  --url URL          URL to the resource
  --timeout TIMEOUT  Connection timeout
```

```sh
~ python3 script.py -h --timeout --port
usage: script.py [--timeout TIMEOUT] [--port PORT]

optional arguments:
  --port PORT        Port to the resource
  --timeout TIMEOUT  Connection timeout
```

This naively assumes that you are only using `sys.argv`, I'm not really sure what would need to be done if it weren't.

Comment: Looking at Kilian's answer I think there may be a nice middle ground where you maintain the default `-h/--help` action and add a new action that explains parameters.

Comment: That could make sense too! An --arghelp command or something.

Comment: I've just added an `ExplainParamAction` example. I think the flag `--arg-help` is quite a good name for it

Answer (score 1):

This has been discussed here: [Customize argparse help message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35847084/customize-argparse-help-message)

In essence, you can overwrite the help by adding --help as argument.

Edit: the custom help could be pointing to a syntax for getting help on a specific parameter like -s parameter_you_wish_help_about.

Edit 2: Haven't tested it, but something along this lines.

```
parser.add_argument('-s',action='store',dest='para', type=str, help='Get Help on specific parameter')
parser.add_argument('-h', '--help', action='help', default=argparse.SUPPRESS, help='Use -s to get help on specific parameter')

help_dict={}
help_dict['para_1']='Help on para_1'
print (help_dict[args.para])
```

Comment: That looks like it could work. That answer is a little complex though. Can you maybe help unpack it a little for my specific requirement? If it is that complicated to do then probably it isnt really worth it for me...