# Why doesn't my argparse show default values?

Tags: python, argparse

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12151306/argparse-way-to-include-default-values-in-help/12151325?noredirect=1#comment60537455_12151325), this script called "parse_fail.py" should print default=1 when I type:

```
python parse_fail.py --help
```

on the command line, but it doesn't.  Why not?

```
#parse_fail.py

import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
parser.add_argument("--test", type=int, dest='test', default=1)
parser.parse_args()
args_dict = vars(parser.parse_args())
locals().update(args_dict)
print test
```

When I run this script I get:

```
$ python parser_fail.py  --help
usage: parser_fail.py [-h] [--test TEST]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help   show this help message and exit
  --test TEST
```

EDIT: added output of the script.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently you need to include a non-empty help string.

This works:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
parser.add_argument("--test", type=int, dest='test', help="WHY NO DEFAULT???", default=1)
parser.parse_args()
args_dict = vars(parser.parse_args())
locals().update(args_dict)
print test



$ python parser_fail.py -h
usage: parser_fail.py [-h] [--test TEST]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help   show this help message and exit
  --test TEST  WHY NO DEFAULT??? (default: 1)
```

Comment: Simply including a non-empty help string did not work for me (Python 2.7.3).

Using the `formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter` attribute when instantiating argparse.ArgumentParser as shown in @kindall's answer did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You don't get that result because you haven't defined the variable `test`. Instead you get an error message, which actually tells you this. There is nothing in your code that defines `test`, so trying to print it is an error.

You are making two mistakes. First, you're throwing away the return value of `parser.parse_args()`, which is where your command line argument values are stored. To fix this, assign that to some variable.

```
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Second, you're trying to print `test` and not the `test` attribute of `args` (or whatever variable you used). To fix this, print `args.test` rather than `test`.

```
print args.test
```

Since you're only interested in the value of your `test` attribute, you could combine these (although, of course, you will usually want to use more than one argument value, so you probably wouldn't do this in a real script):

```
print parser.parse_args().test
```

Putting it together, this works:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
parser.add_argument("--test", type=int, dest='test', default=1)
print parser.parse_args().test
```

(I can't really figure out how you got the code you posted from the link you gave, which is about including default values in help messages, but hopefully this helps anyway.)

Comment: With that formatter class the default should appear in the help message - but he hasn't showed us that.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question is not about the value of the args object, but why the default value is missing from the help string.