# Python argparse: Show Defaults and keep newlines?

Tags: python, argparse

I want to keep newlines in help text and show defaults of arguments.

I found two answers at Stackoverflow:

- argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter https://stackoverflow.com/a/3853776
- argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter https://stackoverflow.com/a/12151325

How can I enable both features?

Comment: Don't forget that you can include ` %(default)s` in your own `help` lines - along with what ever extra formatting you want.  See https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class SaneFormatter(argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter, 
                    argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter):
    pass
```

Usage:

```
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='''Multi
line
help
text
''', formatter_class=SaneFormatter)
```